# jetsam criteria for closing an app

Tags: ios, low-memory, bluetooth-peripheral

I have an iOS app connected to a peripheral and as such running in the background. Sometimes when there is a low memory situation, jetsam decides to close my app even though according to the jetsam log it is not the largest running process. So far my app didn't get any memory warnings so it is not even possible to respond to such event by releasing resources.

First I would like to know if there are any criteria for closing an app due to a low memory event.

Second, what are the keys in the log? for example the state key - does it represent the current state of the process, i.e. when it is suspended, it means that the app was closed by jetsam? or maybe that was the app's state regardless of the low memory event

Can several processes be closed? Because when I look at all JSONs, only one process has the killDelta key, and it doesn't always happen to be the largest one, and even so I can see that several processes are suspended, meaning again that not only one was closed?

I'd appreciate any help
Thank you